# Does Resizable BAR for the GPU apply to shared memory chipsets?

Tags: linux, memory, gpu, gaming, opengl

From what I understand, resizable BAR is a way to increase the size of the data chunks the CPU can use to send data to the GPU, increasing throughput (please correct me if I'm mistaken).

But, does this even apply to a system with shared CPU/GPU memory like a laptop? The idea there is that the physical memory addresses are accessible by both processors, obviating a need for "transfer" as the kernel should be able to access the same data using the same memory address.

In this case, I don't see how resizable BAR even applies since the same data is accessible by both processors without any need for transfer. Am I getting this totally wrong?

Here is the relevant vulkaninfo output from my AMD Ryzen 9 laptop with 16 GB of main memory and an iGPU:

```
VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties:
=================================
memoryHeaps: count = 1
    memoryHeaps[0]:
        size   = 15931211776 (0x3b5930000) (14.84 GiB)
        budget = 15931211776 (0x3b5930000) (14.84 GiB)
        usage  = 3912351744 (0xe931c000) (3.64 GiB)
        flags: count = 1
            MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT
memoryTypes: count = 1
    memoryTypes[0]:
        heapIndex     = 0
        propertyFlags = 0x000f: count = 4
            MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT
            MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT
            MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
            MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT
        usable for:
            IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL:
                color images
                FORMAT_D16_UNORM
                FORMAT_X8_D24_UNORM_PACK32
                FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT
                FORMAT_S8_UINT
                FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT
                FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT_S8_UINT
                (non-sparse)
            IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR:
                color images
                (non-sparse)
```

Comment: Is there a problem that you are trying to solve, or is this more informational/educational?

Comment: I am not aware of any iGPUs that exists today which actually support BAR.

Comment: @Ramhound That's what I'm seeing as well, which is why I'm wondering if it's even a thing with iGPUs. If the memory is already shared, why the need for it?

Comment: @Synthetix - The memory isn’t shared with dGPUs

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, that's how I understand it. But dGPUs can use resizable BAR. iGPUs share memory, but don't use resizable BAR. I'm trying to understand if this is because shared memory makes resizable BAR unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizable BAR is only useful to increase the buffer size for device to device memory copies, as in CPU memory to (dedicated) GPU memory.

It is a way to enhance bandwidth and latency over PCIe links. From Nvidia [GeForce RTX 30 Series Performance Accelerates With Resizable BAR Support](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/news/geforce-rtx-30-series-resizable-bar-support/)

> Resizable BAR is an optional PCI Express interface technology.

It is not relevant for integrated graphics because there is no physical PCIe link. The iGPU connects to the same memory controller as the CPU and its command bus is connected to the CPU bus, there are no relevant PCIe links for Resizable BAR to be enabled for and any memory copies needed can be done by the same memory controller as is used by the CPU without needing secondary buffers.

From [Intel Gen11 Architecture and GT2 "Ice Lake" iGPU Detailed](https://www.techpowerup.com/253928/intel-gen11-architecture-and-gt2-ice-lake-igpu-detailed) you can see the general architrcture. The LLC is the "Last Level Cache" shared by the CPU and GPU where they both get data from.

[image]

The iGPU has the same access to memory as the CPU, unlike a dedicated GPU which has to rely on it's memory being populated by another device.

The BAR is a basic feature of the PCI interface, and by extension also the PCIe interface, which is essentially a PCI interface running over a fast serial link. The BAR is basically a channel between the GPU command and memory areas and the CPU address space. For more information I recommend reading [What is the Base Address Register (BAR) in PCIe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190050/what-is-the-base-address-register-bar-in-pcie)

The Resizable BAR is an extension that just allows that address space to be changed "on the fly" so that the CPU can essentially blast data into a larger address space on the GPU.

The Resizable BAR is a way for the CPU to be able to push chunks of data to the dedicated GPU, with an integrated GPU it can simply load data into a section of memory allocated to the GPU and then tell the GPU where it is.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you!